# MAMP PHP 5.5.3 will not connect to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

Am new to both PHP and MySQL and trying something very basic. I can connect to my database from Mac's terminal. OS is 10.7.5

```
<?php


try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=comments', 'sadmin', 'password');
    /*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/
    echo 'Connected to database';

    /*** close the database connection ***/
    $dbh = null;
    }
catch(Exception $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

However, when i run this html i only get this on my browser.

```
    getMessage(); } ?>
```

More info:

Wireshark sniffing off of lo0, doesn't show any packets to/from port 3306. I see packets to/from port 80 (apache).

I can see php is working as the below code when saved as phptest.php gives all php info.

```
    <html>
     <head>
      <title>PHP Test</title>
     </head>
     <body>
     <?php phpinfo(); ?> 
     </body>
    </html>
```

(Earlier i had it as phptest.html which didn't work quite well.)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have PDO enabled, along with the MySQL PDO driver?

Comment: You get `getMessage(); } ?>` on your brower? or somekind of error?

Comment: The `mod_php` is not enables in your Apache configuration. This is what you get for using *canned servers*.

Comment: @VasilisLourdas Yes i see them both enabled on MAMP's phpinfo page

Comment: @Glavić No i don't get any error. Its just what i pasted. Same on safari, firefox

Comment: @darkphp Can you connect to MySQL from the mysql client utility using the username/password from the code above?

Comment: @tereško I don't see any of those settings within MAMP's preferences. Where and how do i verify if mod_php is enabled or not?

Comment: Then you don't even have php enabled, like tereško said.

Comment: @VasilisLourdas Yes, i can connect using same credentials from terminal.

Comment: @Glavić Ok some correction, i see PHP in MAMP preferences. Version 5.5.3 is selected and the Cache field under PHP extensions is kind of greyed out. The other version is 5.2.17. Upon selecting 5.2.17, i selected eAccelerator as extension. The situation hasn't changed though ...

Comment: Try to run a `<?php phpinfo();` and see the output.

Comment: Wrote a hello world block in php and i see hello world in browser. (     <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?>). So php seems to be running.

Comment: @VasilisLourdas Yes i just tried 'hello world' in php and got expected result in browser

Comment: @VasilisLourdas For some reason, <?php phpinfo(); ?> gives a blank page

Comment: Well, it appears that php is not configured to run with Apache, as @tereško already said.

Comment: php info was displayed after saving the file as phptest.php